# how to make a textbox with rounded corner in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering how to make a class for textboxes with rounded corners in c#(visual studio). Could anyone please help me. I found a code online to create it but not able to enlarge(stretch) it

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;
using System;

class round : TextBox
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateRoundRectRgn")]
    private static extern IntPtr CreateRoundRectRgn
    (
        int nLeftRect, // X-coordinate of upper-left corner or padding at start
        int nTopRect,// Y-coordinate of upper-left corner or padding at the top of the textbox
        int nRightRect, // X-coordinate of lower-right corner or Width of the object
        int nBottomRect,// Y-coordinate of lower-right corner or Height of the object
                        //RADIUS, how round do you want it to be?
        int nheightRect, //height of ellipse 
        int nweightRect //width of ellipse
    );
    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        this.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(2, 3, this.Width, this.Height, 15, 15)); //play with these values till you are happy
    }
}
```

Comment: Rounded corners are rounded corners.  You should try to apply the techniques you found in the buttons to a textbox.   As is there really is nothing to *help* with - you did not show your attempt and describe a problem

Comment: Simpler to use a borderless TextBox and draw the roundness from the container's Paint event.

Comment: Not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I found a code online to create it but not able to enlarge(stretch) it.

With this code, the control will be resized (stretched) when you rebuild the project.

To apply that in the designer without rebuilding the project, override the *OnResize* event instead of the *OnCreateControl* event.

Replace this:

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
    base.OnCreateControl();
    this.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(2, 3, this.Width, this.Height, 15, 15)); //play with these values till you are happy
}
```

with this:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    this.Region = System.Drawing.Region.FromHrgn(CreateRoundRectRgn(2, 3, this.Width, this.Height, 15, 15)); //play with these values till you are happy
}
```

Good luck.